# Use filename to average data by month

Tags: r, filenames, lapply, read.table

I have an R related question which is to do with having to read in many files and process these files.
Each file is for measurements of ozone made at a different time at a different station. The data is in a table format and I can read the data in using:

```
files <- list.files()
data  <- lapply(files, read.table, skip=19)
```

This gives me a data frame for all the files which I would like to now process. For example the files are named:

```
> head(files)
 [1] "fiji_19980105.dat" "fiji_19980112.dat" "fiji_19980119.dat"
 [4] "fiji_19980130.dat" "fiji_19980206.dat" "fiji_19980213.dat"
```

Where "fiji" is the name of the station and the date is YMD format. I would like to average the data frame to get monthly averages for this station (I will only need to work on one station at a time, so really I just want to average the data frame called data to produce 12  sets of average data).

I imagine I can do this using some ?apply function, but I'm really lost on how to do this. Any suggestions on a solution are really appreciated!

As an example of the result of adding the dates to the data frame here we have:

```
> head(dat)
V1     V2    V3   V4 V5   V6    V7   V8   V9  V10       Date
1 9000 1007.7 0.006 29.6 74 0.59 0.006 9000 9000 9000 1998-01-05
2 9000 1005.2 0.028 29.3 75 0.62 0.006 9000 9000 9000 1998-01-05
3 9000 1001.6 0.060 28.5 78 0.63 0.006 9000 9000 9000 1998-01-05

 > str(dat)
'data.frame':   153994 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ V1  : int  9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 ...
 $ V2  : num  1008 1005 1002 997 993 ...
 $ V3  : num  0.006 0.028 0.06 0.104 0.14 0.169 0.198 0.238 0.271 0.301 ...
 $ V4  : num  29.6 29.3 28.5 27.9 27.6 27.2 27 26.6 26.2 26 ...
 $ V5  : int  74 75 78 79 80 81 82 84 85 85 ...
 $ V6  : num  0.59 0.62 0.63 0.68 0.69 0.7 0.72 0.74 0.75 0.76 ...
 $ V7  : num  0.006 0.006 0.006 0.007 0.007 0.007 0.007 0.008 0.008 0.008 ...
 $ V8  : num  9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 ...
 $ V9  : num  9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 ...
 $ V10 : num  9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 9000 ...
 $ Date: Date, format: "1998-01-05" "1998-01-05" ...
```

Comment: So you want averages of every column? aggregate rather than tapply then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your list of files, get `Date`s:

```
datetimes = as.Date(files, "fiji_%Y%m%d")
```

See `?strptime` for details about the format templates, essentially you can include whatever other values as literal filler, and ignore any trailing characters that don't matter.

The rest requires that you give more information about what is in each data.frame, so give us more information about the data in those.

It would be best to create one large data.frame with these date stamps added to each row, and then go from there.

To get that something like this would work (imagine it's called 'dat' rather than 'data'):

```
dat = lapply(files, read.table, skip=19)

for (i in 1:length(files)) {
    dat[[i]]$Date = rep(datetimes[i], nrow(dat[[i]])

}

dat = do.call("rbind", dat)
```

Then you can use `format(dat$Date, "%m")` to get a value for each date that only includes the month, and `tapply` across that with a summary function (e.g. `mean`). There would be less classical `plyr` versions of this that will no doubt come up soon. :)

It's probably not a good idea to call `read.table` with lapply, so I would change that as well so you can put in basic checks for each I/O and the merging of the data.frames.

Comment: Thanks! I had just written something hiddeous (using 4 tmp variables and lots of unlists) to get to the result for datetimes! I didnt realise R was so smart :)

Comment: thanks for the example. I'm afraid that I am stuck on the suggestion you have of using tapply as I dont quite understand how it works. Each file can potentially be of differnet length. The second variable is pressure, third is height and the data comes from ballons that are launched into the sky (the pop at different altitudes depending). What I would like to create at the end is either a data frame or a list of lists (not sure what the pro/cons are?) that contain the average pressure, heights and ozone (V2, V3 and V7) for Jan-Dec. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: different lengths is fine, that's what tapply is for